# how do I search for an xml tag with the matching closing tag?

Tags: python, xml, regex

I'm wondering what is the best way in python to search & delete an XML tag, content inside it(whatever it is doesn't matter) as well as its closing tag? XML is well formed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could identify the element with XPath and then use the [remove](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.remove) method:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
data = '''\
<node1>
  <node2 a1="x1"> ... </node2>
  <node2 a1="x2"> ... </node2>
  <node2 a1="x1"> ... </node2>
</node1>
'''
doc = ET.fromstring(data)
e = doc.find('node2/[@a1="x2"]')
doc.remove(e)
print(ET.tostring(doc))
# <node1>
#   <node2 a1="x1"> ... </node2>
#   <node2 a1="x1"> ... </node2>
# </node1>
```